# SQLite database on Android - how to remove it?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm using SQLite database for caching. I want to remove this database on my phone, because I have multiple app versions on which I'm working at and some has different database versions. This is causing exception:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 7 to 5
```

I need to remove whole db file on my phone and create it again with older version.

How to access this file and delete it? I should be stored in data folder but I cant see that folder in my phone storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove it from adb shell in Android Studio `adb shell run-as com.package.name cd /data/data/com.package.name/ rm -r databases`

Answer (score 0):

At development time, you can just clear your app's data to delete its databases (and other files). You can clear the data in Android device app settings; accessing that depends on device model and platform version. In recent stock Android versions you can do it e.g. by long-pressing on the app icon in launcher -> app info -> storage -> clear storage.

Comment: I cleared Cache and Storage and uninstalled the App, installed other version from older branch and it still detects database. It is stored outside of app storage.

Comment: If it's not in the app data directory, then you're doing something special to put it there and getting rid of the file depends on that special code.

Comment: By default it should be in Android/data/data but this folder does not exist

Comment: In a non-rooted device you don't have access to it.

Comment: I was able to remove it from adb shell in Android Studio `adb shell
run-as com.package.name cd /data/data/com.package.name/ rm -r databases`